# @PathVariable not working with @RestController

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm trying out Spring Boot and I'm facing a trivial problem. I'm unable to use @PathVariable in @RestController. Here is my controller -

```
package com.harshil.controller;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@RestController
public class UserController {

    @RequestMapping(name = "/user/{id}/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public User getUser(@PathVariable("id") int id) {
        return generateUser(id);
    }
}
```

This is how I'm calling the endpoint - http://localhost:8080/user/1/

In my previous Spring (not Boot) project I used @PathVariable in a @Controller and it worked fine. I just can't figure out what I may be doing wrong. And idea?

Comment: What is exactly "not working" meaning for? Like exceptions, http response etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elements `name` and `value` have different meanings.
See doc:
[RequestMapping](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html)

Replace `name` with `value` in your RequestMapping annotation
`@RequestMapping(value = "/user/{id}/", method = RequestMethod.GET)`

OR

`@GetMapping("/user/{id}/")`
`@GetMapping(value = "/user/{id}/")`

They are just a little shorter.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code-

```
 @RequestMapping(name = "/user/{id}")
        public @ResponseBody User getUser(@PathVariable(value ="id") int id) {
            return generateUser(id);
        }
    }
```

And if you have a service layer write- return serviceLayerName.generateUser(id);